# Java cos function acting weird

Tags: java, trigonometry

When trying to get the cos of 90 using this code

```
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
```

This prints
6.123233995736766E-17
Why does this happen and what have i done wrong

Edit i solved this using a custom function(Where the amounts of zeros is how rounded the number becomes):

```java
double round(double value){
  return((double)Math.round(value * 100000d) / 100000d);
}
```

Thanks too https://stackoverflow.com/users/20459/asterite for the function

Comment: Long story short, the value you are getting back _is_ technically zero, but there are some very small rounding errors, due to the way that floating point (inexact) arithmetic behaves inside a computer.  If you need an _exact_ calculation, then look into using Java's `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how would you represent `pi/2` exactly with `BigDecimal`?

Comment: You are concerned with a value that is out by less than 10 thousand trillionth of a unit yet you say you solved it by increasing the error (rounding) . Your solution has made every other value much less accurate, up to 100 billion times less accurate. You can not increase the precision by rounding,